# Multi-schema data pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We want to create a Spark-based streaming data pipeline that consumes from a source (e.g. Kinesis), apply some basic transformations, and write the data to a file-based sink (e.g. s3). We have thousands of different event types coming in and the transformations would take place on a set of common fields. Once the events are transformed, they need to be split by writing them to different output locations according to the event type. This pipeline is described in the figure below:

[image]

Goals:

- To infer schema safely in order to apply transformations based on the merged schema. The assumption is that the event types are compatible with each other (i.e. without overlapping schema structure) but the schema of any of them can change at unpredictable times. The pipeline should handle it dynamically.
- To split the output after the transformations while keeping the original individual schema.

What we considered:

- Schema inference seems to work fine on sample data. But is it safe for production usecases and for a large number of different event types?
- Simply using `partitionBy("type")` while writing out is not enough because it would use the merged schema.

Comment: Streaming or structured streaming.

Comment: @thebluephantom Structured streaming.

Comment: @Kafels there's not much code to share on what I have tried; as I said, I've tried simply reading with `.config("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", "true")` and writing with `partitionBy("type")`. I'm looking here more for general high level approaches or ideas

Comment: @joarleymoraes did you find a solution to this problem? I am also trying to build something like this using kinesis.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same here, casting everything to string, using marshamallow to validate, and then using from_json in a foreach like in https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/two-topics-two-schemas-one-subscription-apache-spark-structured-streaming/read
seems the more reasonable approach